# How do I create a chart in Jira that counts the number of stories by status in an epic

Tags: charts, jira, kanban

I'm trying to do a chart similar to below one:
I have 4 columns in my KanBan TO-DO, Development, QA, Prod.

I want to select a set of specific EPICS and have them show me the % of stories in each column.
How can I automate this in Jira?

[Jira-Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU20o.png)

I couldn't find documentation related to this, and haven't seen it.